# Isolating HTML element without using iframe

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, iframe

I'm building a `MVC` application with `angular` as client-side framework. I'm loading all views inside tabs; the user can open the same view multiple times and here comes the problem.

when the user opens the same view twice, there will be **duplicated IDs** hence some `html` attributes won't work correctly (e.g "for" attribute for "label" element)

I know, I can generate random IDs to avoid this problem but this's not acceptable in my case.

what i need is to isolate the view root (div element) so it doesn't interfere with other elements, something like `iframe` but without using `iframe` :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why you don't want to generate a sequence of IDs? (Random will not ensure uniqueness).

Comment: for what it's worth, ID's can be variable just like everything else: `<div id={{id}}>Hi</div>`, so that could apply to `for` and `label`'s. Maybe your original problem can be bypassed?

Comment: I can't use generated IDs because the view is somehow designed by the end-user with static IDs, it'll require some string manipulation to apply generated IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. The DOM structure resides inside the `window` and the `document` which follows. There can be only one `window` pr (i)frame.

What you could do, and the most common approach, is to generate UUID for the specific tab/view. This UUID must be available in your backend and is how you direct form posts to the correct context.

Now, while youre generating the HTML for each tab, postfix your ID's with the UUID. Keep in mind though, that if your main view is 100% static without page reloads, the DOM will keep stacking up - and eventually take up a great deal of memory.

Comment: I've implemented this solution already but i thought there may be another way to simulate iframe behavior :)